# How to grant su permission to app after unroot?

Tags: android, su, superuser, rooted-device

**What I want:**

I want my app to use su command to take screenshot in background even after I unroot the phone.

**code example:**

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
val outputStream = OutputStreamWriter(process.outputStream)
outputStream.write("/system/bin/screencap -p\n")
```

**What I tried:**

I thought I will just root my phone and install the app in priv-app folder and then unroot but it's not working like that.

How can I do this?

Comment: How will you make sure that your app is running in the background? The lifetime of an app after closing it is at-most 5secs, irrespective of the fact whether you use it in root or un-root mode.

Comment: if you talk about force stop then I didn't care about this. if not then I don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to grant root access after unrooting. You can give fake root access in termux but it just shows #. So no use.